# Why does my custom class not recognize swift extensions? (i.e. String)

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I have a string extension in which I define a function that calculates the DamerauLevenshtein distance between two different strings. When adding the following code:

```
var result = "Hello"
result.damerauLevenshteinTo("Hellow")
```

in any other class such as a UIViewController, UITableViewController, etc. the code compiles fine.
As soon as I try adding it to my own class defined as  `class CustomClass: AnyObject` I get the following error message.

> Value of type String has no member 'damerauLevenshteinTo'

What am I missing? Thanks!

**Update** Copy pasting the entire class with the extension to an empty project compiles great... Moving it to the old project still gives me the error no matter what I try.

**Update 2** It seems I can't use any custom classes or subclasses inside this class. Hm...

**Update 3** Deleting the file and pasting the class in a new one got rid of the error after about the third time... Hurray

Comment: Have you added the `damerauLevenshteinTo` member to your custom class?

Comment: Post the source code of your String extension. Preferably just the part where you declare this method

Comment: change class CustomClass: AnyObject to class CustomClass: NSObject

Comment: @RashwanL not good with terminology, mind explaining what you mean?

Comment: @HitendraHckr still the same error :(

Comment: @cyril, in you class that you don´t have an error were you can use `damerauLevenshteinTo`you must have some reference to be able to get that. Add the same reference to your own class.

Comment: @RashwanL nope there's nothing :/ What's more is that copy pasting the class to an empty project works fine as well

Comment: Is it a String extension or NSString extension? Is the extension inside a framework? Is it public?

Comment: @Sulthan it's technically an NSString extension (so the error is `Value of type NSString has no member 'damerauLevenshteinTo'`)  but I wanted to simply things for the sake of the question and no and yes to the rest of the questions

Comment: Most probably your custom class source file is "disconnected" from the rest of you project. I'd try recreating the class source file in Xcode, making sure it's included into your XCode project.

Comment: @cyril dont simplify. That makes us unable to answer.

Comment: did you try cleaning your xcode project? mysteriously and very rarely this helps in some cases but I think the problem is not like that.

Comment: @Sulthan my bad, didn't think it'd make a difference here

Comment: @Stefan I've tried many times :(

Comment: @dfri that seemed to have solved it.... Weird, thanks!!

Comment: @cyril That's good to hear, happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you add the class with the extension? I added some classes into my project which included extensions, and the rest of the code wouldn't recognize the extensions. It appears that this was because I had added the files using "Create folder references" option instead of "Create groups" option. I deleted what I had added, then added them again with "Create groups" option selected. This fixed it for me.

I'm didn't pursue why using references might result in this behavior, because I had intended to add them with the "Create groups" option to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I removed extension file and create new one then paste my code in, it worked.